# Nuxt.js can't set cookie, "undefined (reading 'set')" (cookie-universal-nuxt)

Tags: javascript, cookies, nuxt.js

When trying to set a cookie with `cookie-universal-nuxt` in my router middleware I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
```

What is causing this?

> nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
],
```

> router.js (router middleware)

```
export default async ({ app }) => {

    app.$cookies.set('cookie-name', 'cookie-value', {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    });
}
```

I tried logging in different places:

When I run `console.log(app.$cookies)` in the router it returns undefined.

When I run it in a component (so: `console.log(this.app.$cookies)`) it returns `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')`.
I am using the composition-api so I also tried `console.log(context.root.$cookies)` but this also returns undefined.

Comment: Your code looks fine, so I'd encourage you to share some more information. It looks like $cookies is not being added to your nuxt context for some reason- can you access it from anywhere else within your app? Try "this.$cookies" for example in a component.

Comment: When `console.log(app.$cookies)` it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, but where in your app are you running ```console.log(app.$cookies)```? For example, within the script tags of a component you'd need to refer to ```this.app.$cookies```. Elsewhere in your app, ```this``` may not refer to the root Vue instance on which ```app``` and ```$cookies``` etc should be available. Please provide more detail :)

Answer (score 1):

solution:

> *nuxt.config.js*

```
  modules: [
    ['cookie-universal-nuxt', { alias: 'cookiz' }]
  ],
```

> *router.js (router middleware)*

```
export default async ({ app }) => {
    app.$cookiz.set('cookie-name', 'cookie-value', {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    });
}
```